# Shared Calendar is not showing up in azure get calendar connector for Office 365

Tags: azure, office365, azure-logic-apps

I have a shared calendar in Office 365 with read and write permissions and I am trying to get it using Get calendar (V2) connector but it is only getting my own calendar. Is there a way to get shared calendars for  Office 365 in Azure logic apps?

Comment: Hi Ayaz, I found one of the screenshots has something wrong. I have update it, please check my solution. If it helps your problem, please accept it as answer, thanks~

Answer (score 0):

For this problem I did some test and it seems the "Get calendar (V2)" action in logic app can't get the calendars which others shared to you. But I provide another solution(use graph api) below for your reference:

**1.** You need to ask others to share a calendar to you on [office 365 web page](https://outlook.office365.com/calendar/view/month) but not in outlook app.
[image]
[image]

**2.** Then you need to create an application in your azure AD, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application).

In the application you created in azure ad above, please do the steps below:
[image]
[image]

After that, please do not forget click the "Grant admin consent for xxx" button(Maybe you need to wait a few minutes until this button become clickable).
[image]

Then click "Certificates & secrets" in your application in azure ad and new a client secret.(copy this client secret to your note book)
[image]

**3.** Then create a "HTTP" action in your logic app and refer to the screenshot below to request for the access token.

[image]

The "client_id" is your appliction id in azure ad, "username" and "password" is your azure user name and password, the "client_secret" is what you got above. This "HTTP" action will help us to get the access token. The response should be like below:
[image]

Then we need to parse the response data in json type, you can use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action.
[image]

Use the "Body" from the "HTTP" action and fill in the "Schema" box with the code below:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "access_token": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "expires_in": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "ext_expires_in": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "scope": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "token_type": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

**4.** After that, we can create another "HTTP" action in logic app and request the graph api for all of the calendars which you can see (please note there is a space between the "Bearer" and the "access_token").
[image]

**5.** At last, we can get all of the calendars in the second "HTTP" action's "OUTPUTS" box.
[image]

Hope it helps~