# Create New Calendar (not events) Using PowerApps MS Flow

Tags: dynamic, outlook, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I can see there are plugins to create events in existing calendars but is there a way to create a completely new calendar in Outlook BEFORE you add the new event using [MS-flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz5wt.png)?
Essentially I want to automate the 'Add Calendar' you can do on Outlook OWA.

Comment: Hi, as far as I know, there aren't any actions in MS-flow which can create calendar. But maybe we can do it with some workaround, may I know the "source" of your email account in your azure active directory user list (in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAZKv.png)) ? "Azure Active Directory
" or "External Azure Active Directory" ?

Comment: @HuryShen I am using a trial account - it isn't connected to any Azure Account - is there any workaround for it?

Comment: I'm afraid not. If you use a email account in your azure ad, there is a workaround which may implement your requirement.

Comment: @HuryShen is there a online post to show this so I can read it? - willing to give it a try if I get a paid azure instance (plus it would be useful for other people that may have my same requirement)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882979/shared-calendar-is-not-showing-up-in-azure-get-calendar-connector-for-office-365/59893025#59893025) is a post with the solution I provided in the past, this post is for list the calendars but it's similar to yours

Comment: @HuryShen not quite what I needed but useful anyway - I have no idea why such a simple functionality isn't available as standard...