# How to send the Large data file from blob storage to Sharepoint in azure Logic App?

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, chunks, blobstorage

am getting Invalid Template Error, need to send the file from Blob storage to Sharepoint Createfile]

Where the file size is 109.29 MiB.

[[Error:
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Create_file_2' inputs at line '1' and column '3144': 'The template language function 'body' cannot be used when the referenced action outputs body has large aggregated partial content. Actions with large aggregated partial content can only be referenced by actions that support chunked transfer mode.'. ]

How to send blob storage .xlsx huge file to Sharepoint when Create the file

Image of logic app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcQvH.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Sharepoint connector doesn't support transfer large files even though blob connector supports chunk files for transferring large file. You can raise your voice for feature request on this [page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/33577948-sharepoint-online-connector-to-support-chunk-uploa).

For a workaround, you can use [microsoft graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-upload-a-new-file) to upload the file from blob to sharepoint. Before request this api, you need to get a access token from app in azure ad and then use this access token as Authorization bear token. Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882979/shared-calendar-is-not-showing-up-in-azure-get-calendar-connector-for-office-365/59893025#59893025) which use another graph api in logic app for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can sharepoint rest api along with azure function app for transferring large files. You should use small byte arrays to so that you won’t run out of memory. If you are using a trigger in logic app, you will need to used dountill step in logic app to make sure the file is completely uploaded since the sharepoint trigger gets triggered even before file is created

Comment: Can you provide more details on how this works, perhaps an example @Balamurali Pati ?