# Microsoft Flow or Logic apps send file from sharepoint to an API too large

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am trying to send an file from sharepoint to an API.
I get an error that the filesize is too large, it is 120Mb.
Is there anyway to get around this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the http Message size limit, you could find it here:[HTTP limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits).

You can use [chunking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages) to workaround this limits, if the connector supports it. And if enable chunking there is still limit:Message size with chunking is 1GB.

Comment: The problem is not the HTTP request but getting the content from the file from sharepoint

Comment: The sharepoint node "Hent filinnhold" is the same as "Get file content" node.

Comment: It's not http action, but it use http request to get file.

Comment: So what you are saying is that i need too change the way to get the file content from sharepoint? With the use off HTTP? Then use the content from the http to send it with http to my destination?

Comment: I mean the SharePoint has this limit, and looks like for now sharepoint connector doesn't support chunking, check [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/33577948-sharepoint-online-connector-to-support-chunk-uploa) there is a request for this feature. So if you could use http  action to get file content that would be best(need chunking).

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, sharepoint connector doesn't support chunking as George mentioned. So we can't transfer large file by sharepoint connector easily in logic app. But we can use [microsoft graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for download sharepoint file as a workaround.

Before request this api, you need to get a access token from app in azure ad and then use this access token as Authorization bear token. Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882979/shared-calendar-is-not-showing-up-in-azure-get-calendar-connector-for-office-365/59893025#59893025) which request another graph api in logic app for your reference. You can follow the steps in this post to know how to get the access token and request the graph api.